# There is a list of running apps displaying on my tecno 7cs always

Tags: tecno-n3

There is a list of running apps displaying on the right hand side of my Tecno 7Cs. It begun when I accidentally tapped something (I can't remember) after I connected it to a USB. How can I get rid of it?[image: Tecno 7Cs display]

Comment: Look inside Settings - Developer options.

Answer (score 2):

You have made your 'Show CPU Usage' enabled in debugger mode,

Go to settings-----> (Scroll Down) Developer Options-----> (scroll to bottom) Show CPU Usage -----> disable it.